# Dlink DIR-600 significantly slowing connection speed

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, internet-speed

```
Mode     Download speed
------------------------
Wired    1.3 Mbps
DIR600   15 Kbps
```

I don't understand this network thing well, just configured my router:

[image: DIR-600 wireless basic configuration]

I also don't think there's a **channel** issue, since there's no other wireless device "provider" working on my house (maybe my neighbors, but I also don't think this is the case, they all very *yeared*).

I have already tried chaning some of these basic configs, but none seemed to work.

Comment: Are you using "newer" devices to connect to the router? iPhone 4+ and newer laptops etc? If so, change the 802.11 Mode to "n only" to ensure you are using the latest and fastest tech. Also you should try some different channels to see whether that affects speeds. Remove any wireless (DECT) telephones you might have around the router too...

Comment: Actually my parents got iPhone 3Gs.... Is that a problem for the 802.11n mode?

Comment: yeah that is a problem. the 3Gs does not support 802.11n at all. You would have to put the router in mixed mode. 

Did you play around with a wifi stumbler software to see whether there are conflicting channels around? That can really help things. 

Have you upgraded the router to its latest firmware yet? You can also check if you might want to install DD-WRT on it and play around. http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database